# Installing Apache OpenOffice 4.1 on a web server

Tags: openoffice

What is the reason for installing Apache OpenOffice on a web server? Is it to access OpenOffice from a web browser, or am i missing something? If you can install it locally what is the point of installing it remotely?

Comment: Would you care to explain how did you come up with this question? Does it your favourite server distro install it by default? Or your sysadmin tells you he needs it on his webservers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common mistake to believe that Apache OpenOffice has something to do with Apache, the Web Server. They are both maintained by The Apache Software Foundation, that has many varying [projects](http://projects.apache.org/indexes/quick.html).

Apache OpenOffice is purely a desktop software that [requires](https://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/source/sys_reqs_aoo41.html) X-Server to run. There is no need to have it on a machine that is purely a web server. It cannot be run inside a browser. Probably you *could* have it installed on a system also providing desktop software as VNC or Citrix based services.

However, in most cases you end up having both on a same machine when you don't have a dedicated web server but the web server is running on someones desktop computer. Or if the server is some out-of-box system that has desktop environment pre-installed. Not very smart, but yet happens all the time.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for your answer, thats what i assumed, but i thought i would double check anyway

Answer (score 2):

Installing OpenOffice remotely and running it in headless mode enables server-side file conversions from different MS office formats (WinWord, Excel, PowerPoint) to PDF or other formats. This is used by many open-source document management systems, for example. So, depending on your needs, it makes perfect sense to make use of the import/export abilities of OpenOffice server-side.

Comment: Sounds a bit bloat to install whole GUI application suite for just a couple of conversions. Is there any lightweight version with just the command line tools?